# find the last non zero byte in a binary file, how?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, file-corruption

I have a huge binary file padded with nulls in the end, and I want to find the last non zero/null byte, especially its offset from the start of the file.

Looking for some command line solution.

Comment: Tools available and skillset are important, but I expect: open file, seek to LOF (read the byte at LOF (or LOF-1)), iterate backwards one byte at a time. Otherwise, read; if not null, store index; repeat til eof; emit stored value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say nothing about which tools you have at hand or which OS you have, but assuming you have access to standard unix tools like xxd and grep you could do something like this:

`xxd my_binary_file | grep -E ": [0-9,a-f, ]*[1-9,a-f]+"`

The above command will filter out the part of the file only presented as 0000.

Answer (score 2):

For small-ish files:

```
hexdump -C file | tail
```

The `hexdump` utility compresses consecutive lines with the same contents, so discarding all but the last ten lines of output show you the last place where the output gets repetitive.

For larger files, use

```
dd if=file bs=1M skip=$n count=1 | hexdump -C | tail
```

for different values of `$n`, doing a binary search. Eg. for a 700 GB file, you'd start with `skip=350000`, if the output comes back all-zeros, you go down half to `skip=175000`, if it shows non-zero bytes, you go up to `skip=525000`, halving the step size in each iteration. This assumes that there are no large blocks of zeroes inside the file, but for large files is significantly faster.

Comment: Thank you! `hexdump` turned out to be a command I used multiple times recently.